# Word or phrase for "still going on" in this context

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Talking about university admission:

> Admission is still going on.

Can I say : Admission is still **in date?**

And, admission is **out of date,** for showing contrast?

Please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A particular university might accept applications between 1 February and 1 May for starting studies in August.

- In January, you can say **Admission is not yet open / has not yet opened / has not yet started**
- In April, you can say **Admission is open / still open**
- In June, you can say **Admission is closed / has closed / is completed / has completed**

We don't use **out of date** in this context.

- **Your passport is out of date** = It is no longer valid
- **Your clothes are out of date** = They are no longer fashionable
- But **Your clothes are up to date** = They are fashionable

There are not many phases where you can easily use **in date**.

- (informal) **Is this milk still in date?** = Is it still within its printed shelf life?

Comment: Jonathanjo ......I also have a question. Please tell: Can we use 'Admission is close' or 'Admission is complete' in your third example, just as 'Admission is open' in your second example?

Comment: "*Admission is close" is incorrect, "admission is complete" is somewhat awkward. "Is open" and "has closed" are the most ordinary.